# Image caching on Android 6.0

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am having problems with Appcelerator Titanium caching on Android 6.0 devices. I've tried using 5.2.2 and 5.3.0 to no avail.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create an image view and set image to the url you want to cache.
2. Open app on Android 6.0 device with internet connectivity.
3. Image loads up.
4. Close application
5. Turn off wifi
6. Open app

On 5.0 devices, the image is loaded without an issue from the cache. On 6.0, it's loading the default image. I thought this was going to be solved by the fix included on 5.3.0, https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20470, but apparently it's a separate issue.

Is this happening to anyone else? Is there a workaround for 6.0 devices?

Comment: the ticket says its merged into 5.4. Perhaps try and test a nightly build: http://builds.appcelerator.com.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html#5_4_X to see if its fixed now

Comment: add your test code

Comment: Thanks miga, doesn't seem to be working with 5.4.0 either

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the same issue as described in the linked ticket. Image is not saved in temp directory so not cached. However the issue is fixed in SDK 5.4.0 which is not officially released yet. But you can try the continuous build. For installing the sdk run the following command in CLI.

```
appc ti sdk install --branch 5_4_X 5.4.0.v20160608165242
```